# StyleCop Team Development concrete steps

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, stylecop

I am trying to set up a Visual Studio 2015 solution in the way that StyleCop checks for the C# style and once committed to the source control other developers don't need to do anything else to follow the same style rules and get the same errors/warnings from StyleCop automatically.

As the [StyleCop documentation page](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation) and [GitHub StyleCop](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/Integrating-StyleCop-into-MSBuild) describe (both actually say the same) under the title **Team Development**:

> copy all of the files from {Program Files}\MSBuild\StyleCop into a custom folder

in my case under *C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7* there is just one file: *StyleCop.Targets*

Searching for any StyleCop.dll drives me to another folder (*C:\Program Files (x86)\StyleCop 4.7*) with many subfolders, dll's, xml, exe, lex...

**Now my questions:**

Which are exactly the needed files to be uploaded into the project and hence to the source control?

Which are the changes to be done in the configuration project?

*Note:*

Until now I see the contextual StyleCop menus that allow me to make code analysis and checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the install, you would need to have each developer install the StyleCop program on their machines, (and on any build server).

There is an easier way... instead use the `StyleCop.MSBuild` nuget package for each project:

[image]

This adds a StyleCop directive to each csproj, pointing at the instance within the packages folder, this means that it is transferable to each dev machine, and any build servers without them needing to do anything.

Then once there is no errors in a project, use StyleCop.Error.MSBuild to keep it that way, again from nuget:

[image]

This adds `<StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>` to the csproj, but again keeps it within nuget which I personally find an easier way to track things.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even I could not find it in the Package-Manager, but no problem when entering in the Package Manager Console: "Install-Package StyleCop.MSBuild".